# Errors using JQuery with node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm

I have a fresh install of node.js running on Windows 7, and I am trying to run a very basic JQuery script, named `a.js`, which contains just:

```
require("jquery");
$().jquery;
```

Unfortunately, this will not run with JQuery, giving me a TypeError:

```
C:\Users\Ian>node a.js

C:\Users\Ian\node_modules\jquery\lib\node-jquery.js:10
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.withCredentials = false;
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at create (C:\Users\Ian\node_modules\jquery\lib\node-jquery.js:10:26)
    at C:\Users\Ian\node_modules\jquery\lib\node-jquery.js:9435:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ian\node_modules\jquery\lib\node-jquery.js:9437:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ian\a.js:1:63)
```

I have found a few bug reports on this error through Google, most of which suggest downgrading JQuery. However, when I do that, I just get a different error. The below is with JQuery 1.6.3:

```
C:\Users\Ian>node a.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'location'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at create (C:\Users\Ian\node_modules\jquery\node-jquery.js:6:33)
    at C:\Users\Ian\node_modules\jquery\node-jquery.js:9065:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ian\node_modules\jquery\node-jquery.js:9067:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Can anyone suggest what may be wrong? I have tried various reinstallations of the software with no luck. I have tried both `npm install -g` and `npm install` for both the default version of jquery and also jquery@1.6.3.

Edit: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063058/keep-getting-error-for-browserless-jquery-in-node?rq=1) - as yet unanswered - seems related.

Comment: Why are you running jQuery on the server-side?

Comment: No good answer sorry @SLaks - I'm making use of someone else's code which runs JQuery on the server side. When I failed to get that working, I came up with my trivial test example to ensure that the problem was only with the JQuery part, and not anything else in the other person's code.

Comment: @Ina Yeah but that's the problem, jQuery is not a serverside library, it relies on stuff not present in node.

Comment: @JakubHampl so do you believe there is no workaround? I'm given to believe the code I inherited worked well enough. I can get some way along by manually installing packages (such as location, above) but I eventually run into a TypeError. I'd also appreciate any links you can provide around jQuery not being a serverside library, https://npmjs.org/package/jquery seems to imply it is, but I'm new to this and could easily be wrong.

Comment: @SLaks sometimes you re-use libraries written for the browser on the server-side.

Comment: Just saying: The Use Case for jquery on the server side: if you wanted to request the html of a given page from a node server and then manipulate its DOM, for instance, separate all its images and catalog them, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If ur on node 0.10.x ... run sudo npm rebuild

https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/issues/35

Comment: This got me earlier as well.  I was running ubuntu.  Apt get only gets you 0.6.  Upgraded to 0.10 and then this error.  Cleaned out the node_modules and reran npm install.

Answer (score 3):

In the git page for the jquery-nodejs project, says that does not works on Windows, so the problem is your OS.
https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery

Comment: I'm having the same problem but on Mac OS X. Might have something to do with node 0.10.0 as I didn't see it happening before the upgrade.

Comment: This isn't really accurate: contextify doesn't build easily on Windows, but you can make it happen using node-gyp if you install the required MS build tools. Once you do that, jQuery should be installable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the module to the `$` variable:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
$().jquery;
```

Comment: True, but the error happens on line 1, so it's not the undefined `$`.

Comment: Thanks @zeMirco, unfortunately that doesn't change any of my errors.

Comment: The error must be in the rest of your code that you didn't show us. The first error says `window.XMLHttpRequest` is undefined.

Comment: I just downgraded from node v0.8.12 to v0.8.11 but that hasn't helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on REHL and sudo npm rebuild solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those running Windows, the **npm rebuild** may not work and you might still see something like:

```
C:\Projects\NODE\paragraphs\node_modules\jquery\lib\node-jquery.js:10
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.withCredentials = false;
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Found [this solution](https://github.com/UncoolAJ86/node-jquery/issues/52) thanks to user [NeverI](https://github.com/NeverI) that did the trick for me:

In node-jquery.js (found under \node_modules\jquery\lib) change the lines:

```
if(window == null ) {
    window = require('jsdom').jsdom().createWindow();
```

to:

```
 if(!window || !window.document) {
    window = require('jsdom').createWindow();
    window.document = require('jsdom').jsdom();
```